# How to manage a telegram bot using a sqlite3 database when two users use it in the same time

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram, entitymanager

I have created a telegram bot that, depending on your location (made up of your city and your stop), defines the times when the scheduled bus passes through your location. The bot, created with a python library called Botogram, works great! I never thought about how to manage more than one user using the bot at the same time (I thought the telegram API thought about it). Involuntarily I created a database that memorized the users' choices to make the localization system work, after which I also inserted a box in which the chat.id was inserted. The bot works great even when two users use it in close times, but if they use it at the same time the warning: `sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked`. Which means that the database is not multitasking but supports one action at a time. I kindly ask how you can solve this problem and make the database more dynamic.

```
connloc = sqlite3.connect("request.db") #open the database


@bot.command("start") #function active when typing on the telegram /start chat
def start_command(chat, message, args):
    bot.api.call('sendMessage', {
        'chat_id': chat.id,
        'text': 'Welcome, what do you want to do?',
        'reply_markup': json.dumps(keyboard_selection)}) #sending a message in Json style
    item = chat.id
    item2 = "db"+str(chat.id)
    try:
        sqlloc = ("create table {} (" \
        " chat_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"\
        " locpar varchar(20)," \
        " stoppar varchar(20)," \
        " locdes varchar(20) ," \
        " stopdes varchar(20));".format(item2))
        connloc.execute(sqlloc)
        cloc = connloc.cursor()
        cloc.execute("INSERT INTO {}(chat_id) VALUES (?);".format(item2), (item,))
        connloc.commit()
    except:
        return #after command /start, create a new table in the database, if it already exists, because this bot is an always active bot (there are other choices besides the /start)



@bot.message_matches('Main menù')
def tomain_command(chat, message):
    bot.api.call('sendMessage', {
        'chat_id': chat.id,
        'text': 'Welcome back, what would you like to do?',
        'reply_markup': json.dumps(keyboard_selection)}) #This is a substitute function at / start, as I said you only click on the / start only the first time, as an alternative to each bot cycle end you can, indeed you must use this function
    item = chat.id
    item2 = "db"+str(chat.id)
    try:
        sqlloc = ("create table {} (" \
        " chat_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"\
        " locpar varchar(20)," \
        " stoppar varchar(20)," \
        " locdes varchar(20) ," \
        " stopdes varchar(20));".format(item2))
        connloc.execute(sqlloc)
        cloc = connloc.cursor()
        cloc.execute("INSERT INTO {}(chat_id) VALUES (?);".format(item2), (item,))
        connloc.commit()
    except:
        return

@bot.message_matches('Look for your stop times now')
def send_lol(chat, message):
     bot.api.call('sendMessage', {
        'chat_id': chat.id,
        'text': 'Well select your town',
        'reply_markup': json.dumps(keyboard_locpo)}) #This function allows you to choose the city where you are, in fact the reply markup is the telegram keyboard containing all the cities

@bot.message_matches('Do a new search')
def send_lol(chat, message):
     bot.api.call('sendMessage', {
        'chat_id': chat.id,
        'text': 'Chose the town when you are',
        'reply_markup': json.dumps(keyboard_locpo)}) #This is another function, which is activated only at the end of the bot search, if you want to make a new search (I repeat it is not necessary to press / start)






#This is the first function (@bot.process) that analyzes the first message sent by the initial function (which allows you to choose the city). It inserts your choice in the database if what you have written is equal to at least one of the cities containing in the result list
@bot.process_message He then enters the city in the locpar box (where the departure cities are located). And finally a keyboard is activated that allows you to choose one of the stops in your city
def name_loc(chat, message):
    item = chat.id
    item3 = "db"+str(chat.id)
    cloc = connloc.cursor()
    varcheck = cloc.execute("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE chat_id= (?)".format(item3), (item,))
    varop = []
    for items in varcheck:
        for items2 in items:
            varop.append(items2)
    for i in result:
        if message.text == i and varop[1] == None and varop[2] == None and varop[3] == None and varop[4] == None:
            item = i
            item2 = chat.id
            cloc = connloc.cursor()
            cloc.execute("UPDATE {} SET locpar = (?) WHERE chat_id = (?);".format(item3), (item,item2))
            connloc.commit()
            for t in result[i]:
                        keyboard_stops = {"keyboard": [[{"text": t} for t in pair] for pair in zip(result[i])]}
            bot.api.call('sendMessage', {
                            'chat_id': chat.id,
                            'text': 'Perfect, choose your stop bus',
                            'reply_markup': json.dumps(keyboard_stops)}) #fermata 1


#Now this function inserts the stop you have chosen in the database and activates a keyboard that allows you to choose the destination city (always present in result)
@bot.process_message
def name_stop(chat, message):
     item = chat.id
     item3 = "db"+str(chat.id)
     cloc = connloc.cursor()
     varcheck = cloc.execute("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE chat_id= (?)".format(item3), (item,))
     varop = []
     for items in varcheck:
         for items2 in items:
             varop.append(items2)
     for i in result:
      for t in result[i]:
         if message.text == t and varop[1] != None and varop[2] == None and varop[3] == None and varop[4] == None:
             item = t
             item2 = chat.id
             cloc = connloc.cursor()
             cloc.execute("UPDATE {} SET stoppar = (?) WHERE chat_id = (?);".format(item3), (item,item2))
             connloc.commit()
             bot.api.call('sendMessage', {
                                    'chat_id': chat.id,
                                    'text': 'Now, choose the town that you want to reach',
                                    'reply_markup': json.dumps(keyboard_locpo)}) #città 2

#This function inserts the city you want to reach in a key database and activates that allows you to choose the station you want to reach
@bot.process_message
def name_loc2(chat, message):
     item = chat.id
     item3 = "db"+str(chat.id)
     cloc = connloc.cursor()
     varcheck = cloc.execute("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE chat_id= (?)".format(item3),(item,))
     varop = []
     for items in varcheck:
         for items2 in items:
             varop.append(items2)
     for i in result:
           if message.text == i and varop[1] != None and varop[2] != None and varop[3] == None and varop[4] == None:
               item = i
               item2 = chat.id
               cloc = connloc.cursor()
               cloc.execute("UPDATE {} SET locdes = (?) WHERE chat_id = (?);".format(item3), (item,item2))
               connloc.commit()
               for t in result[i]:
                           keyboard_stops = {"keyboard": [[{"text": t} for t in pair] for pair in zip(result[i])]}
               bot.api.call('sendMessage', {
                               'chat_id': chat.id,
                               'text': 'Now, select the stop you want to reach',
                               'reply_markup': json.dumps(keyboard_stops)})




#The last function also inserts the stop you want to reach in the database and activates the algorithm that allows you to select the times (which fortunately has no errors and does not interest us, called 'researchedot(lf [1], lf [2], lf [ 3], lf [4], chat.id)')
@bot.process_message
def name_stop2(chat, message):
     item = chat.id
     item4 = "db"+str(chat.id)
     cloc = connloc.cursor()
     varcheck = cloc.execute("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE chat_id= (?)".format(item4), (item,))
     varop = []
     for items in varcheck:
         for items2 in items:
             varop.append(items2)
     for i in result:
          for t in result[i]:
              if message.text == t and varop[1] != None and varop[2] != None and varop[3] != None and varop[4] == None:
                  item3 = t
                  item2 = chat.id
                  cloc = connloc.cursor()
                  cloc.execute("UPDATE {} SET stopdes = (?) WHERE chat_id = (?);".format(item4), (item3,item2))
                  connloc.commit()
                  cloc = connloc.cursor()
                  varcheck = cloc.execute("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE chat_id= (?)".format(item4), (item,))
                  lf = []
                  for items in varcheck:
                      for items2 in items:
                          lf.append(items2)
                  ricercatot(lf[1],lf[2],lf[3],lf[4],chat.id)
                  cloc.execute("UPDATE {} SET locpar=NULL, stoppar=NULL, locdes=NULL, stopdes=NULL WHERE chat_id = (?);".format(item4,), (item,))
                  connloc.commit() #After activating and closing the algorithm and sending data to the user, the database is emptied, so as to allow the database always ready to insert new data without interrupting or compromising the bot (the chat remains marked .id to make it recognizable). In fact, remember that the / start command is replaced by other commands (those shown above). In these processes you also identified '''if message.text == i and locpar = None''' is an easy way to check if the database is free without compromising it.
```

[image: Main page of the database, here we can find all users tables, where are registred all their choices, each table is called using chat.id's user adding db]
[image: Here, we can see the table, divided in 4 columns (first chat.id, second town when you are, second the stop where you are, third the town you want to reach and last the stop you want to reach.]

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     bot.run()
```

Comment: If you need to write from multi clients at same time, sqlite is not a good choice. Time to move to another database solution. But you can create a queue for tasks. If db is locked, just add this task to queue then produce this tasks when database is available.

Comment: Do you know how you can create things (do you happen to have documentation)? What do you recommend for another database system?

Comment: Postgresql is the one of populer SQL database solution. But you wont able to use them like sqlite, you need a running database server (in local or remote, doesnt matter). Queue's is one of easiest things on python. You just need threaded worker to produce queue and do database operations. Also you need to send replies in worker. Anyway, using a real server-based database solution will be best.

Comment: Ok thank you a lot

Comment: Sqlite is perfectly fine for this application. I think that the problem stems from the fact that you are creating a new table too often (look at the code). Instead, you have to think at the logic of your program and create tables (or insert values) only when needed. Sqlite supports out of the box multiple readers but only one writer.